# color effect on map (python plotly)

Tags: python, plotly

I create a basemap for US and  want to fill in color with temperature  value.

I want to fill the map with  the color effect like the  following picture.

But now I could only hand code the color value like  'red','orange'  and 'purple' and could not get the effect.

Any suggestion to help me to start the search? 
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Do you use some external libaries? I would recommend OpenCV and it's function `applyColorMap`, but if you want to stay inside of python, i think you should make some kind of lookup table and then apply it to image.

Answer (score 1):

Looks at this [example](https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/basemap-maps/). On this [step](https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/basemap-maps/#make-contour-graph-object) you can change `colorscale` parameter (and color changed on whole basemap).

I suggest you for first look at this forum [answer](https://community.plot.ly/t/what-colorscales-are-available-in-plotly-and-which-are-the-default/2079) and choose what colorscale you want the most (based on that [page](https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/color-scales/)). Such `colorscale="Jet"`.

Next, if that did not what you are looking for, then you can create a custom [colorscale](https://plot.ly/python/colorscales/#custom-contour-plot-colorscale), specifying what color you want at each steps of colorscale.

Such this:

```
colorscale=[[0, 'rgb(166,206,227)'],[0.25, 'rgb(31,120,180)'],[0.45, 'rgb(178,223,138)']\
,[0.65, 'rgb(51,160,44)'],[0.85, 'rgb(251,154,153)'],[1, 'rgb(227,26,28)']]
```

But be warned! If you trying to update basemap example from plotly docs, check `zmin` and `zmax`. In example `zmin=-5` and `zmax=5`, so changed steps in custom colorscale if want custom colorscale:

```
colorscale=[[-5, 'rgb(166,206,227)'], [-3, 'rgb(31,120,180)'], [-1, 'rgb(178,223,138)']\
    , [1, 'rgb(51,160,44)'], [3, 'rgb(251,154,153)'], [5, 'rgb(227,26,28)']]
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful to start.